# Как определить, что ноутбук проснулся?

Tags: javascript

Как можно определить, что ноутбук полностью проснулся? **Важно именно полное пробуждение.** Я смотрел по консоли и было видно, что даже находясь в состоянии сна, ноубтук время от времени подключается к сокету, а потом снова отключается. Это вводит меня в ступор. Есть ли какой-то действенный и правильный способ?

Comment: По потреблению энергии. Сон - мал, бодрствование - много.

Comment: Пока никак нельзя однозначно определить.

Comment: Какой именно уровень сна? Что именно вы видели?

Comment: JavaScript не имеет доступа к нижележащим уровням аппаратного обеспечения и не может определить состояние устройства